# PHP jdmonthname() returns wrong month name

Tags: php, date-conversion, julian-date

I am having this problem with  **jdmonthname()** function in php. In my project I have used jdmonthname() in two places. One is working good. But the other one is returning wrong results. I am getting my input from passed into URL(example: http://localhost:8000/doctor_profile/1/2017-03-28).

`$schedules['monthName'] = jdmonthname(strtotime($returnCalenderMonth['requestedCalenderMonth']), 1);`

where **$returnCalenderMonth['requestedCalenderMonth']** has the data '2017-03-28' as string and returns **'January'** where it should be March. On input '2017-1-28' it returns **'April'** instead of January etc. etc..

I have checked and found that strtotime() function is returning correct value with Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools. I have searched but could not find any reference to this problem. E.g, I am using PHP 5.6, Ubuntu 16.4 x64, Laravel 5.4 for my project.

I will be grateful if somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like `$returnCalenderMonth` is the problem. `jdmonthname()` expects a **Julian day number**, and you are passing it a timestamp (`strtotime('2017-3-28')` returns `1490659200`, when you **should** be passing it `2457840`).

Comment: Julian date for 2017-03-28 is 2457840, where are you doing that conversion? A Julian date is the number of days since Jan 2nd, 4713 BC (the supposed creation of the earth). It isn't the same as a unix timestamp

Comment: My Bad! You are right! Thank you @ObsidianAge and Mark Baker ! I wonder how is it working in the other part of the program then?? I have used ISO timestamp there too.